# Page reload in IOS devices using javascript in

Tags: javascript, ios, responsive

The screens in my IOS device doesn't reload after clicking the back button. It works using PC and android devices. Is there specific reload code for IOS device?

here is my code

````
```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var goBackButton = document.getElementById("goBackButton");

    if (goBackButton) {
      goBackButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location.reload();
        window.history.back();
     });

      goBackButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.href
        window.history.back();
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```
````

I was expecting it to reload the screen so it updates the newly fetched data after clicking the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to navigate to the previous page without using `window.history.back()`, you can achieve this by accessing the `document.referrer property`, which contains the URL of the previous page.

Here's how you can modify your script to achieve this:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var goBackButton = document.getElementById("goBackButton");

    if (goBackButton) {
      goBackButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location.href = document.referrer;
      });

      // Handle touch events for mobile devices
      goBackButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
        window.location.href = document.referrer;
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It works both in ios and pc. and it's even shorter code

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS has unique behavior when it comes to managing history and caching pages. The best method is to use the `pageshow` event, which is triggered when a page is navigated back to, and `persisted` event which tells if a webpage is loading from a cache or not.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(event) {
       let page = event.target;
       if (page.id === "yourPageId") { 
          if (event.persisted) {
              window.location.reload();
          }
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: hi! I also tried this but has trouble with the pageiD

Comment: To fix this, you need to ensure that the page you want to reload has an id attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

- When you call window.location.reload() and then window.history.back(), Safari first reloads the page and then navigates back to the previous page. This causes the page to be reloaded twice, which is why it doesn't update with the new data.
- You can use the window.history.go(-1) method instead of window.history.back(). This method navigates the browser to the previous page in the history, without reloading the current page.

  ```
  <script>
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     var goBackButton = document.getElementById("goBackButton");

     if (goBackButton) {
      goBackButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location.reload();
        window.history.go(-1);
      });

      goBackButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
        window.history.go(-1);
      });
    }
  });
  </script>
  ```

Comment: thank you for this feedback. I tried but it still doesn't work on IOS.